# How to split a Elements in scala into a Array of Strings

Tags: arrays, scala, jsoup

I have some troubles into slitting an Element (scraped from the web) into an Array of Strings.

Here is my code :

```
link = "http://www.myurl.com"
val doc: Document = Jsoup.connect(link).get()
val title2 = doc.select("li > h3 > a").toString
```

that give me :

```
<a href="/association/129033/69-1ere-compagnie-d-arc-du-dauphine.htm">1ERE COMPAGNIE D'ARC DU DAUPHINÉ</a>
<a href="/association/129512/69-38sms.htm">38SMS</a>
<a href="/association/128940/69-40-batteurs.htm">40 BATTEURS</a>
<a href="/association/129543/69-4l-four-liberty.htm">4L FOUR LIBERTY</a>
<a href="/association/129820/69-a-bord-perdu.htm">A BORD PERDU</a>
```

what i want is to have only the href in a Array of Strings. Only take the strings in the " ".

I've try to use JavaConverters like asScala, but i'm falling working with it :/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply extract href attributes from the a you get like:

```
doc.select("li > h3 > a").map(link -> link.attr("href")).toArray
```

take a look the more attribute extracting features from Jsoup

Comment: did you mean : `doc.select("li > h3 > a").map(doc -> doc.attr("href")).toArray` ?    also map make an error (map not a member of org.jsoup.Elements)

Comment: i do not have how to test it but try this -> `doc.select("li > h3 > a").asScala.map(doc -> doc.attr("href")).toArray` . Let me know it it helps